# Use Pandas to take Monthly Averages of data in a .csv file and save by Year in new .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Python 3.6, Pandas 0.22.0:
I have imported a .csv file called Data.csv. It contains weather data with columns "NAME" "DATE" "SNOW" that references the location name, the date in MM/DD/YYYY format, and the amount of snowfall on that day. I want to group all rows by "NAME", then calculate monthly averages of "SNOW" so the output displays one row for "NAME", "DATE" (as a single, monthly entry), and "SNOW" with the average for the month. My "DATE" column is in datetime format. These entries are over years 2016 and 2017. After everything is grouped by monthly snowfall average, I need to make two new .csv files for each year - 2016, 2017. Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep = ',')
df1 = df.loc[:, ["NAME","DATE","SNOW"]]
df1["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE)
date['DATE'] = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq="M")).mean()
df1.to_csv('meansnow2017.csv', sep = ',', header=True)
```

The "DATE" column was originally an object. I cannot figure out how to layer these groupby statements in a way that makes sense. This gives me the desired column headers, but does not group my "DATE" by month or calculate my averages. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html